# xcode 4.3 compare strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, xcode4.3

I want to know how to copmare first letter between two strings, like string1 begins with letter 'a' and string2  begins with letter 'b' then string1 must displayed first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't strictly conform to UNICODE string comparison rules, which are complex for non-latin alphabets, but is quick at least:

```
NSString *first = [string1 characterAtIndex:0] <= [string2 characterAtIndex:0] ? string1 : string2;
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use

```
NSComparisonResult order = [firstString compare:secondString];
```

instead. ([NSComparisonResult docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult))

Comment: +1 You are right, but mine's quicker I'll bet ;-)  And actually is closer to the OP's question in which he just wants the first character compared, not all the characters...

Comment: Surely `[[firstString substringToIndex:1] compare:[secondString substringToIndex:1]]` would exactly answer the question set?

Comment: @Tommy but that's an extra call to substringToIndex -- if the strings always begin with the same letter, in any reasonable implementation the comparison won't go beyond the first different character.

Comment: @H2CO3 yes, but otherwise if you have the two strings 'Bat' and 'Bristol' then if you chop just one down to B rather than both then you'll always get an ascending or a descending result rather than a same. Furthermore, it'll depend which way around you happen to pass in the strings, so unless you're careful you'll see apparent sort order changing autonomously.